# "Deprecated Main Class" warning when executing Feature file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

When I run the feature file as Cucumber Feature, I get the error below:

```
cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use 
io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
```

I'm not getting snippets for my steps.

My login feature file

```
Feature: Login

Scenario: Successful Login with valid credentials
Given User Launch Chrome browser
When User Opens URL "http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/login"
And User enters email as "admin@yourstore.com" and Password "admin"
And Click on Login
Then Page Title Should be "Dashboard /  administration"
When User Click on Log out Link
Then Page Title should be "Your store. Login"
And Close browser
```

I have added all necessary dependencies in pom.xml like

- cucumber-core
- cucumber-html
- cobertura
- cucumber-java
- cucumber-junit
- cucumber-jvm-deps
- cucumber-reporting
- hamcrest-core gherkin
- selenium-Java
- Junit

Comment: Please edit your question and include the proper stack-trace. The interesting thing may be on another line than line 57.

Also, please include the smallest scenario file you can create where the problem still exists. And a minimized pom.xml where the problem still exists.

At the moment you have shared snippets and your own assumptions and your problem persists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are using `cucumber-jvm-deps ` your dependency managment is wrong. Try starting from scratch with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton